# Fitting array in beamer

Tags: beamer, arrays

I want to fit the array within the width of my slide.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\newcommand\x[1]{\color{myblue}{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\y[1]{\color{lava}{\mathbf{#1}}}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Matrix Inverses}

\underline{Understanding Elementary Matrices}
\begin{itemize}
\item if $\mathbf{A}=   \left[ \begin{array}{rrrr}
 a & b & c \\
d    &e &f  \\
g & h & i \\
\end{array}\right],$ then $\ldots$
\item[]

$
\mathbf{E}_1\mathbf{A}=\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
   \left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 \underline{ 1}\rlap{\underline{~~~~}}  & \underline{0} \rlap{\underline{~~~~}} & \underline{ 0} \\
0     & 1 & 0   \\
  \x{ -4}  & \x{\ 0}  &\x 1  \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{rrrr}
 a & b & c \\
d    &e &f  \\
g & h & i \\
\end{array}\right]= \onslide<2->{\hspace{-3em}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.25}
\left[ \begin{array}{llllll}
\pause 1\times a \pause +0 \times d \pause +0 \times g & =\y a 
& \pause 1\times b \pause +0 \times e \pause +1\times h \pause &=\y b 
& \pause 1\times c \pause +0 \times f \pause +0 \times i \pause & =\y c \pause \\ 
\pause 0 \times a \pause +1 \times d \pause +0 \times g & =\y d 
& \pause 0 \times b \pause +1 \times e \pause +0\times h \pause & =\y e
& \pause 0 \times c \pause +1 \times f \pause +0\times i \pause&  =\y h \pause \\ 
\pause \x{-4} \times a \pause + \x{0} \times d \pause + \x{1}\times g & =\y{-4a+g}
& \pause \x{-4} \times b \pause + \x{0}  \times e \pause +\x{1} \times h \pause & =\y{-4b+h}
& \pause \x{-4}\times c \pause + \x{0}  \times f \pause +\x{1} \times i \pause & =\y{-4c+i}\pause \\ 


\end{array}\right]}
$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the 3x3 array to fit in the slide, I believe it's necessary to set the length parameters `\arraycolsep`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip` to close or equal to zero. Either that, or reduce the font size. I think that shrinking the length parameters to close to zero is the lesser of two evils.

The following screenshot shows the output of the 37th and final page of the document. Observe that I changed the layout of the array from `llllll` to `rlrlrl`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\newcommand\x[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\y[1]{\textcolor{lava}{\mathbf{#1}}}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Matrix Inverses}

\underline{Understanding Elementary Matrices}

\bigskip
If $\mathbf{A}=   
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f  \\
\,g & h & i 
\end{bmatrix*}$, then $\ldots$

\bigskip

$\mathbf{E}_1\mathbf{A}=
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
 \underline{1} \rlap{\underline{~~~~}} & 
 \underline{0} \rlap{\underline{~~~~}} & 
 \underline{0} \\
 0 & 1 & 0     \\
 \x{-4} & \x{0} & \x 1  
\end{bmatrix*}
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  a & b & c  \\
  d & e & f  \\
\,g & h & i 
\end{bmatrix*}= $

\medskip

\onslide<2->{\hspace*{-2em}
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\medmuskip=0mu  % spacing around binary operators
\thickmuskip0mu % spacing around relational operators
$\left[\begin{array}{@{} rlrlrl @{}}
  \pause 1 \times a \pause +0 \times d \pause +0 \times g \pause               &= \kern2pt \y a 
& \pause 1 \times b \pause +0 \times e \pause +0 \times h \pause               &= \kern2pt \y b 
& \pause 1 \times c \pause +0 \times f \pause +0 \times i \pause               &= \kern2pt \y c \\ 
  \pause 0 \times a \pause +1 \times d \pause +0 \times g \pause               &= \kern2pt \y d 
& \pause 0 \times b \pause +1 \times e \pause +0 \times h \pause               &= \kern2pt \y e
& \pause 0 \times c \pause +1 \times f \pause +0 \times i \pause               &= \kern2pt \y f \\ 
  \pause \x{-4} \times a \pause + \x{0} \times d \pause +\x{1} \times g \pause &= \kern2pt \y{-4a+g}\kern6pt
& \pause \x{-4} \times b \pause + \x{0} \times e \pause +\x{1} \times h \pause &= \kern2pt \y{-4b+h}\kern6pt
& \pause \x{-4} \times c \pause + \x{0} \times f \pause +\x{1} \times i \pause &= \kern2pt \y{-4c+i}\kern2pt
\end{array}\right]$
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```